# The "project-centennial" tag should be merged with the "desktop-bridge" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[project-centennial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-centennial) is the project name for what became the [desktop-bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desktop-bridge). They are completely redundant and [always come together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-centennial%20not%20desktop-bridge?mode=all).

They should be merged and [project-centennial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-centennial) should be a synonym for [desktop-bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desktop-bridge) just like [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi), [win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32), [win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32api) and [windows-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-api).